# How to test if a JSONObject is null or doesn't exist

Tags: java, android, json

I have a set of `JSONObject` values which i receive from a server and operate on. Most times I get a `JSONObject` with a value (let's say statistics) and sometimes, it returns an `Error` object with a code and a description of the error.

How do I structure my code so that it doesn't break if it returns the error. I thought I could do this, but doesn't work.

```
public void processResult(JSONObject result) {
    try {
        if(result.getJSONObject(ERROR) != null ){
            JSONObject error = result.getJSONObject(ERROR);
            String error_detail = error.getString(DESCRIPTION);
            if(!error_detail.equals(null)) {
                //show error login here
            }
            finish();
        }
        else {
            JSONObject info = result.getJSONObject(STATISTICS);
            String stats = info.getString("production Stats"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the problem at the moment?

Answer (score 140):

Use `.has(String)` and `.isNull(String)`

A conservative usage could be;

```
    if (record.has("my_object_name") && !record.isNull("my_object_name")) {
        // Do something with object.
      }
```

Comment: funny enough i used the isNull() method alone but had the same trouble.

Comment: Post the JSON message you get with the key ERROR and provide the type of exception and we'll sort this in no time. :)

Comment: Did you get this sorted @sparrow?

Comment: What is the difference between "has" and "isNull"? Why do I need both?

Comment: @OceanLife if you use isNull(String s), you may skip has(String s). The isNull(String s) checks the same as has(String s), and additionally checks if value is 'null'

Answer (score 16):

It might be little late(it is for sure) but posting it for future readers

You can use [`JSONObject optJSONObject (String name)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optJSONObject(java.lang.String)) which will not throw any exception and

> Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONObject, or null otherwise.

so you can do

```
JSONObject obj = null;
if( (obj = result.optJSONObject("ERROR"))!=null ){
      // it's an error , now you can fetch the error object values from obj
}
```

or if you just want to test nullity without fetching the value then

```
if( result.optJSONObject("ERROR")!=null ){
    // error object found 
}
```

There is whole family of [opt functions](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) which either return `null` or you can also use the overloaded version to make them return any pre-defined values.
e.g

[`String optString (String name, String fallback)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> Returns the value mapped by name if it exists, coercing it if
>   necessary, or fallback if no such mapping exists.

where `coercing` mean, it will try to convert the value into String type

---

A modified version of the @TheMonkeyMan answer to eliminate redundant look-ups

```
public void processResult(JSONObject result) {
    JSONObject obj = null;
    if( (obj = result.optJSONObject("ERROR"))!=null ){
       //^^^^ either assign null or jsonobject to obj
      //  if not null then  found error object  , execute if body                              
        String error_detail = obj.optString("DESCRIPTION","Something went wrong");
        //either show error message from server or default string as "Something went wrong"
        finish(); // kill the current activity 
    }
    else if( (obj = result.optJSONObject("STATISTICS"))!=null ){
        String stats = obj.optString("Production Stats");
        //Do something
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not parse JSON Object!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, optString was what we needed

Answer (score 12):

In JSONObject there is a 'Has' method that you can do to Determaine the key.

I have no idea if this will work but it looks Credible.

```
public void processResult(JSONObject result) {

    if(result.has("ERROR"))
    {
        JSONObject error = result.getJSONObject("ERROR")
        String error_detail = error.getString("DESCRIPTION");

        if(error_detail != null)
        {
            //Show Error Login
            finish();
        }
    }
    else if(result.has("STATISTICS"))
    {
        JSONObject info = result.getJSONObject("STATISTICS");
        String stats = info.getString("Production Stats");

        //Do something
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not parse JSON Object!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If in any case, your jsonobject is null.
Then use this statement for checking jsonobject is null or not.

```
if (!obj.get("data").isJsonNull()){
   //Not Null
}else{
   //Null
}
```

And for checking jsonobject is exist or not, use .has:

```
if (!obj.has("data")){
   //Not Exist
}else{
   //Exist
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is sometimes more convenient and less ambiguous to have a NULL object than to use Java's null value.

- JSONObject.NULL.equals(null) returns true.

  JSONObject.NULL.toString()returns "null".

Example:

System.out.println(test.get("address").equals(null)); // Preferred way
System.out.println(test.getString("address").equals("null"));

source -- JSONObject oracle docs

Answer (score 0):

Just a note:

With EE8 json specs, I can do an exception-safe get:

```
result.asJsonObject().getString("ERROR", null);
```

if, however, I want to do a check I can do it with:

```
result.asJsonObject().get("ERROR").equals(JsonValue.NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

If at any point in your code, `org.json.JSONObject json_object` becomes `null` and you wish to avoid `NullPointerException` (java.lang.NullPointerException), then do check it as below:

```
if(json_object == null) {
   System.out.println("json_object is found as null");
  }
  else {
       System.out.println("json_object is found as not null");
  }
```