# Asserting that value inside JSON is null

Tags: java, json

I have a json where I want its values down in a map, unless that value is NULL, if it is I just want an empty string instead.

I've tried a few different view of telling what the value I get out of the json is, but none of them seems to be able to tell the value is null.

```
if (!isNull(json.get("id"))) {
   orderDataMap.put("id", json.get("id"));
} else {
   orderDataMap.put("id", "");
}

if (!isNull(json.get("sr"))) {
   orderDataMap.put("sr", json.get("sr"));
} else {
   orderDataMap.put("sr", "");
}
if (!isNull(json.get("systemOrderId"))) {
   orderDataMap.put("systemOrderId", json.get("systemOrderId"));
} else {
   orderDataMap.put("systemOrderId", "");
}
```

in the if statement I've also tried using `json.get("id") != NULL` as well as `json.get("id").equals(null)`

Here's how it looks while debugging:
[image: debugger]

Comment: please check:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585492/how-to-test-if-a-jsonobject-is-null-or-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JSONObject.isNull to check if a value is not present or is null.

```
if (json.isNull("id")) {
    orderDataMap.put("id", json.get("id"));
    } else {
    orderDataMap.put("id", "");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution